# Dynamic ID / Dynamic Functions / Jquery Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html, dynamically created.

```
<a class="open"></a>
<div class="dialog"></div>
<a class="open"></a>
<div class="dialog"></div>
<a class="open"></a>
<div class="dialog"></div>
<a class="open"></a>
<div class="dialog"></div>
```

Using the follwing jquery, I'm assigning ID's to each a aswell as each div

```
$('a.open').prop('id', function(i){
return '' + (i + 1);
});
$('div.dialog').prop('id', function(i){
return 'dialog' + (i + 1);
});
```

I'm then using the assigned ID's to trigger a jquery ui Dialog pop-up, however, I'm having to rewrite the function below for x number of times. Is there a way to create the below function so I do not have to rewrite it x number of times. (x being the max. number of times the the divs may appear on page).

```
$("#1").click(function(){
   $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an ideal use for data attributes.  When you dynamically generate the `<a>` tags, assign them a data attribute like so:

```
<a class="open" data-openNumber="1"></a>
```

(You can also do this via jQuery, of course).

Then all you have to do is write a single click handler:

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.open', function(){
    var num = $(this).data('openNumber');
    $('#dialog'+num).dialog( 'open' );
});
```

Note that I don't attach the handler *directly* to elements with class `open`; if I did that, I would have to do it every time the elements were dynamically created.  Instead, I attach the handler to the body, and *filter* it by class `open`; that way I don't have to keep re-declaring that click handler.  If you have a more handy enclosing class, you can use that instead of `body`, but not knowing your page structure, I didn't know what that element would be, so I just used `body`.

I made a jsFiddle to demonstrate the concept.  I hope it's helpful:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jammerwoch/Z9U67/

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce, this has been bugging me all day, had to hardcode the solution, I'll give you the answer first thing in the morning when I try this out.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

**HTML**

```
<a class"open" data-id="1">open</a>
<div class="dialog" data-id="1"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", ".open", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $(".dialog[data-id="+ id +"]").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using the id attribute to listen for clicks later on. It makes more sense to create a single event listener for the group.

```
$("a.open").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find(".dialog").dialog("open")
});
```